# Using ASP.Net MVC 4/C# Datacache object is confusing users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am new to the whole datacache thing. I am building an app for a client who has potential to grow substantially so I am using the datacache instead of Session variables so that I can have multiple servers.

I have been in development mode and this has worked just fine, but it has just been me.

Now we are testing and completely new people on a computer that have never been to the site before are being recognized as another user somehow...

I do use cookies to remember a user, but these guys are coming in for the first time so that can't be it. Never had this problem with Session variables so I must be doing something wrong with the datacache.

Why does the datacache confuse the users? How do I prevent this?

Thanks!
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cache = server level, session = user level.  Your server is saving the cache data and passing it along to the users.  If you have intentions of having multiple users connected, and storing separate data for each, sessions is actually the correct way to do it.

As for performance, yes there will be a slight performance hit, but it shouldn't be too drastic unless you've got a massive amount of users hitting the site at one time or you're storing huge amounts of data to the session.

Comment: I have read that Session variables do not work when you are using multiple servers...say Azure...because the way that they load balance User A could bounce from Server 1 to Server 2 between each ajax call and therefore the user information would be lost. Is this incorrect?

Comment: ah...correct, by default that is how the behavior is, however you can change it to use SQL to store the session state, take a look here for details on that.. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604/EN-US  This isn't quite as effective as storing it at the application level, obviously, however you don't run the risk of the data being lost during server switches in load balancing.

Comment: I am using Azure Table Storage for my database so that isn't really an option (unfortunately). So...in this instance, multiple servers, no SQL, how are you supposed to persist user data so that it isn't shared between users?

Comment: Is it an option to be just purely cookies? I don't need to store much information...ID and such. I am already using encrypted cookies for when the cache expires. I could simply load the info into a hidden variable while they are interacting with the site...

Comment: There are a couple of other options available, such as state server or custom, take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx Since you're using cloud based SQL storage, i think state server may be your best option -- it basically runs as a separate windows service and will store and retrieve all the session information, even if the application itself has to be restarted.  Cookies may also be a viable option if you're not storing any sensitive data.

Comment: It isn't anything sensitive and it is encrypted...might be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Session to store a logged in users credentials and other session specific information. Datacache is used to store application wide data that can be quickly accessed, things like xml files used on the website or perhaps a dataset used by anyone on the website. Session is a unique id and "thread" for each user for their specific user name and all other information related to their logged in id.